# 'Waiting for all target devices to come online' when running android app on tcp

Tags: android, android-studio, tcp, ip, wifi

I am trying to connect my phone with android studio over tcp to run apps on wifi without using usb. I am using following steps to connect:

adb tcpip PORT

adb connect ip:PORT

For PORT I am using 5555. Both my phone and my laptop are on wifi too. When I disconnect usb and run adb devices, terminal shows me that device is connected. But when I run my app android studio says 'Waiting for all target devices to come online' and it just keeps on loading until I connect my usb and the app runs over usb.

I don't have any idea why this is happening. I have started using MacBook Pro recently. I didn't face any issues in windows though. I am also using the latest update of android studio which is arctic fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2. It's very irritating to see 'Waiting for all target devices to come online' every time I try to connect and run app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try killing the adb process as it is probably stuck.
Open the terminal and use the following command:

```
killall adb
```

This will kill all the processes that started the `adb` command.
Sometimes the adb process is forked and there are multiple instances of it and Android Studio seems to get stuck for this weird reason.

Then you can retry connecting to your phone again tryig:

```
adb connect ip:PORT
```

Comment: Didn't work. I googled and found out that some phones easily connect if they have wifi debugging on. I have Samsung s9 plus which doesn't have wifi debugging option in developer options but it connected for few days and apps were running too. Now it is connecting but apps are not running.